# Getuikit uk-slideshow generated with ng-repeat not showing images

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, getuikit

Hey guys I have a problem with uikit slideshow + angularjs. When I am using ng-repeat trying to bring all images to uk-slideshow then images are not showing. Is there someone has similar problems? When I remove ng-repeat tag from div images are coming back. I am very confused right now.

```
<div class="uk-width-1-2" ng-repeat="property in properties">
    <div class="uk-slidenav-position" data-uk-slideshow="{animation: 'scroll'}">
        <ul class="uk-slideshow">
           <li ng-if="property.pictures.length > 0" ng-repeat="pp in property.pictures">
               <img src="../img/2_wide.jpg" />
           </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-previous" data-uk-slideshow-item="previous"></a>
        <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-next" data-uk-slideshow-item="next"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is ` <img src="../img/2_wide.jpg" />` hard-coded? Shouldn't that be a dynamic?

Comment: its just testing. It can be dynamic `<img ng-src="../img/{{ pp.picture }}">`. The problem is when I removing all ng tags then slider is working. when i put it back then it wouldnt

Comment: Maybe images appear after slideshow initialization, so try to add data-uk-observe next to data-uk-slideshow

Answer (score 0):

Just add "data-uk-check-display"

```
<div class="uk-slidenav-position" data-uk-slideshow="{animation: 'scroll'}" data-uk-check-display>
```